# Dynamic created radio buttons wont execute event on click

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a button named "Add Radio Button" in my form, and a text box named TexBox1.

I've written code that when I click the "Add Radio Button", it generates a Radio button; it's own name:

c#:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

public partial class Default2 : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            ViewState["Counter"] = 0;
        }
    }
    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i <= Convert.ToInt32(ViewState["Counter"]); i++)
        {
            HtmlGenericControl div = new HtmlGenericControl("div");
            RadioButton rb = new RadioButton();
            rb.ID = i.ToString();
            rb.Text = "Button" + i.ToString();
            rb.GroupName = "RB";
            rb.CheckedChanged += radioButton_CheckedChanged;

            div.Controls.Add(rb);
            Panel1.Controls.Add(div);
        }

        ViewState["Counter"] = Convert.ToInt32(ViewState["Counter"]) + 1;
    }
    private void radioButton_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        RadioButton btn = sender as RadioButton;
        TextBox1.Text = btn.Text;
    }

}
```

ASP

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Default2.aspx.cs" Inherits="Default2" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>

        <asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server">
        </asp:Panel>
        <br />
        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        <br />
        <br />
        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" OnClick="Button1_Click" Text="Add RadioButton" />

    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

The problem is that after several radio buttons being created, I want the program to work as if each of them is checked, the TextBox1.Text gets the radio button's text string (the name of button) but the function radioButton_CheckedChanged doesn't execute.

Answer (score 2):

You missed this I think

```
rb.CheckedChanged +=new EventHandler(rb_CheckedChanged);
```

Check my comments below also

Comment: Still, I'm running it on my side and I'm having trouble. I'll post something if anything changes. Hang in there

Comment: Dude, you have to also create a postback, the radio button, created dinamically or not, in it's CheckedChanged doesn't trigger a postback

Comment: Thanks for the replies...i did add the code eventhandler, and the post back...when i click on the radioButtons, all of them disapear, and textbox only remains in the page without any string...i have to click the button too see the rb,s again

Comment: You could create a list of radio buttons in code behind, store them in the Session state, and not create new ones. Then in the load, you just retrieve them. Maybe that's why they're not triggering the event

Answer (score 0):

you should set as true to Autopostback property

```
 rb.AutoPostBack = true;
```

Comment: Reply appreciated. Set the autoPostBack true, in the Button1_click code, butwhen i click on the generated dynamic radio buttons, the whole page seems to be refreshed and all radio buttons disappear plus textbox remains empty

Comment: As far as I can see in you code, you can use a RadioButtonList control. So You will not have to write more code.

Answer (score 0):

```
this is how its should be imo:

protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i <= Convert.ToInt32(ViewState["Counter"]); i++)
        {
            HtmlGenericControl div = new HtmlGenericControl("div");
            RadioButton rb = new RadioButton();
            rb.ID = i.ToString();
            rb.Text = "Button" + i.ToString();
            rb.GroupName = "RB";
            rb.CheckedChanged += +=new EventHandler(radioButton_CheckedChanged);

            div.Controls.Add(rb);
            Panel1.Controls.Add(div);
        }

        ViewState["Counter"] = Convert.ToInt32(ViewState["Counter"]) + 1;
    }
    private void radioButton_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        RadioButton btn = sender as RadioButton;
        TextBox1.Text = btn.Text;
    }
```

Comment: It would be helpful to explain what is different here from the original, problematic code. I don't want to have to do a diff to discover what you've changed.